# AVAudioplayer initialize component throws a null exception

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.ios

```
string mediafile;
mediafile=Constants.AudioLink;
NSUrl url1=new NSUrl(mediafile);
var audioplayer=AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(url1);
```

URL is getting link correctly but audio player getting value null. It throws an exception below:

```
Could not initialize an instance of the type 'AVFoundation.AVAudioPlayer': the native 'initWithContentsOfURL:error:' method returned nil.
```

It is possible to ignore this condition by setting : `MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false`

What can i do, Please give me the solution.

Comment: That error is due to the fact that your `NSURL` does not point to a valid/existent file. Try opening your media file with `var myLocalMedia = AudioToolbox.AudioSource.Open (new NSUrl(mediafile), AudioFilePermission.Read, AudioFileType.MP3);` Change the `AudioFileType.MP3` to one that is correct(and supported) for your file. Is `myLocalMedia` null? If so, you will not be able to create an `AVAudioPlayer` from that NSURL.

Comment: is there any player to play audio songs in ipad

Comment: "Audio songs"? CoreAudio supports ~15 different audio container/types, what type of media do you have exactly?

Comment: Those are players, not media types.

Comment: what are the media types and can u give me the sample to play audio with any player or media type?

Comment: See the answer that I added and the check that I am doing to avoid the error that AVAudioPlayer is throwing in your example

Answer (score 4):

These is a really quick example of loading/playing an `.mp3` file that has a build type of `BundledResource` (I dropped into the `Resources` folder of the project) and thus is placed in the app's root directory).

I do a quick check via `AudioToolbox.AudioSource.Open` to make sure the file exists, can be read, and is a valid media file type so I know that `AVAudioPlayer` will not throw a fatal error trying to load it.

```
AVAudioPlayer player; // Class level object ref
partial void playButtonTouch (UIButton sender)
{
    if (player != null && player.Playing)
        player.Stop ();
    else {
        var mp3File = "WildTurkeysEN-US.mp3";
        var mp3URL = new NSUrl (mp3File);
        Console.WriteLine (mp3URL.AbsoluteUrl);
        var mp3 = AudioToolbox.AudioSource.Open (mp3URL, AudioFilePermission.Read, AudioFileType.MP3);
        if (mp3 != null) { 
            Console.WriteLine (mp3.EstimatedDuration);
            player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl (mp3URL);
            player.Play ();
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine ( "File could not be loaded: {0}", mp3URL.FilePathUrl );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mp3url can taken the value but mp3 is getting null value,so unable to play the audio.

Comment: The creation of a `NSUrl` object does NOT valid that the file exists, so if you are getting a null value for `mp3` the file can not be loaded. That can be due to that the file does not exist or that it is not a valid media type based upon the `AudioFileType.XXX` that you are trying to loading (`MP3` type in my example)